# How to speed up the mongo aggregation over milion documents

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, query-optimization

I have a MongoDB database with an **orders** collection where sample document looks like this:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "6596a9974ff34552c1dfce0b"
  },
  "createdAt": {
    "$date": "2024-01-04T10:28:38.542Z"
  },
  "updatedAt": {
    "$date": "2024-01-04T17:05:43.332Z"
  },
  "startedAt": {
    "$date": "2024-01-04T17:05:43.332Z"
  },
  "sentAt": "2024-01-02T15:59:27.266+00:00",
  "deliveredAt": "2024-01-03T02:53:03.662+00:00",
  "price": 163.9,
  "address": "33330 Gayle Field, Brockton, Czech Republic.",
  "shippingCosts": 0,
  "_restaurantId": {
    "$oid": "6596a9964ff34552c1dfba16"
  },
  "_userId": {
    "$oid": "6596a9954ff34552c1df507c"
  },
  "products": [
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "6596a9964ff34552c1dfba1a"
      },
      "name": "Rustic Cotton Pants",
      "image": "https://loremflickr.com/640/480/food?timestamp=17",
      "unityPrice": 3.7,
      "quantity": 2
    },
     ...
  ]
}
```

And i basically want to get the top 3 selling products from all the orders, I have over milion documents in the collection and this aggregation:

```
[
  {
    $project: { products: 1, _id: 0 }
  },
  {
    $unwind: { path: '$products' }
  },
  {
    $group:
    {
      _id: '$products._id',
      unitsSold: {
        $sum: '$products.quantity'
      }
    }
  },
  { $sort: { unitsSold: -1 } },
  { $limit: 3 }
]
```

Takes about 28 seconds to finish. I've trieds using indexes but none of which I've tried are working. I'm new to Mongo and I don't know where to go from here.

Here's the raw explain plan

```
{
  "explainVersion": "2",
  "stages": [
    {
      "$cursor": {
        "queryPlanner": {
          "namespace": "krakoweats.orders",
          "indexFilterSet": false,
          "parsedQuery": {},
          "queryHash": "B5767B28",
          "planCacheKey": "7B75CF63",
          "maxIndexedOrSolutionsReached": false,
          "maxIndexedAndSolutionsReached": false,
          "maxScansToExplodeReached": false,
          "winningPlan": {
            "queryPlan": {
              "stage": "PROJECTION_SIMPLE",
              "planNodeId": 2,
              "transformBy": {
                "products": true,
                "_id": false
              },
              "inputStage": {
                "stage": "COLLSCAN",
                "planNodeId": 1,
                "filter": {},
                "direction": "forward"
              }
            },
            "slotBasedPlan": {
              "slots": "$$RESULT=s6 env: { s3 = 1704378186638 (NOW), s2 = Nothing (SEARCH_META), s1 = TimeZoneDatabase(America/Barbados...Africa/Freetown) (timeZoneDB) }",
              "stages": "[2] mkbson s6 s4 [products] keep [] true false \n[1] scan s4 s5 none none none none lowPriority [] @\"94866bf3-24aa-47e3-be4f-30578ec274f8\" true false "
            }
          },
          "rejectedPlans": []
        },
        "executionStats": {
          "executionSuccess": true,
          "nReturned": 1000012,
          "executionTimeMillis": 26636,
          "totalKeysExamined": 0,
          "totalDocsExamined": 1000012,
          "executionStages": {
            "stage": "mkbson",
            "planNodeId": 2,
            "nReturned": 1000012,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 2784,
            "opens": 1,
            "closes": 1,
            "saveState": 1797,
            "restoreState": 1797,
            "isEOF": 1,
            "objSlot": 6,
            "rootSlot": 4,
            "fieldBehavior": "keep",
            "fields": ["products"],
            "projectFields": [],
            "projectSlots": [],
            "forceNewObject": true,
            "returnOldObject": false,
            "inputStage": {
              "stage": "scan",
              "planNodeId": 1,
              "nReturned": 1000012,
              "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 2544,
              "opens": 1,
              "closes": 1,
              "saveState": 1797,
              "restoreState": 1797,
              "isEOF": 1,
              "numReads": 1000012,
              "recordSlot": 4,
              "recordIdSlot": 5,
              "fields": [],
              "outputSlots": []
            }
          },
          "allPlansExecution": []
        }
      },
      "nReturned": 1000012,
      "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 5134
    },
    {
      "$unwind": { "path": "$products" },
      "nReturned": 11543341,
      "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 13643
    },
    {
      "$group": {
        "_id": "$products._id",
        "unitsSold": {
          "$sum": "$products.quantity"
        }
      },
      "maxAccumulatorMemoryUsageBytes": {
        "unitsSold": 2392000
      },
      "totalOutputDataSizeBytes": 7325500,
      "usedDisk": false,
      "spills": 0,
      "spilledDataStorageSize": 0,
      "numBytesSpilledEstimate": 0,
      "spilledRecords": 0,
      "nReturned": 29900,
      "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 26632
    },
    {
      "$sort": {
        "sortKey": { "unitsSold": -1 },
        "limit": 3
      },
      "totalDataSizeSortedBytesEstimate": 759,
      "usedDisk": false,
      "spills": 0,
      "spilledDataStorageSize": 0,
      "nReturned": 3,
      "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 26636
    }
  ],
  "serverInfo": {
    "host": "DESKTOP-NO3L33J",
    "port": 27017,
    "version": "7.0.2",
    "gitVersion": "02b3c655e1302209ef046da6ba3ef6749dd0b62a"
  },
  "serverParameters": {
    "internalQueryFacetBufferSizeBytes": 104857600,
    "internalQueryFacetMaxOutputDocSizeBytes": 104857600,
    "internalLookupStageIntermediateDocumentMaxSizeBytes": 104857600,
    "internalDocumentSourceGroupMaxMemoryBytes": 104857600,
    "internalQueryMaxBlockingSortMemoryUsageBytes": 104857600,
    "internalQueryProhibitBlockingMergeOnMongoS": 0,
    "internalQueryMaxAddToSetBytes": 104857600,
    "internalDocumentSourceSetWindowFieldsMaxMemoryBytes": 104857600,
    "internalQueryFrameworkControl": "trySbeEngine"
  },
  "command": {
    "aggregate": "orders",
    "pipeline": [
      { "$project": { "products": 1, "_id": 0 } },
      { "$unwind": { "path": "$products" } },
      {
        "$group": {
          "_id": "$products._id",
          "unitsSold": {
            "$sum": "$products.quantity"
          }
        }
      },
      { "$sort": { "unitsSold": -1 } },
      { "$limit": 3 }
    ],
    "cursor": {},
    "maxTimeMS": 60000,
    "$db": "krakoweats"
  },
  "ok": 1
}
```

Comment: An index does not help, because you select the entire collection.

Comment: If this is your frequent query pattern, you should consider refactoring your schema to store `product` as individual document instead of sub-documents

Comment: Which version do you use? I see it uses the [Slot-Based Query Execution Engine](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/sbe/). In earlier versions it was not perfect, maybe try the "old" classic execution engine be setting parameter `db.adminCommand({ setParameter: 1, internalQueryForceClassicEngine: true })`

Answer (score 0):

You could try to pre-sum the quantities in the `products` array. Then you should get much less documents from `$unwind` stage:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $project: {
         products: {
            $map: {
               input: { $setUnion: "$products._id" },
               as: 'product',
               in: {
                  $filter: {
                     input: "$products",
                     cond: { $eq: ["$$this._id", "$$product"] }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   {
      $set: {
         products: {
            $map: {
               input: "$products",
               in: {
                  _id: { $first: "$$this._id" },
                  quantity: { $sum: "$$this.quantity" }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   { $unwind: '$products' },
   {
      $group: {
         _id: '$products._id',
         unitsSold: { $sum: '$products.quantity' }
      }
   }
])
```

Depending on your data you could try to reduce the `products` even more like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $project: {
         products: {
            $map: {
               input: { $setUnion: "$products._id" },
               as: 'product',
               in: {
                  $filter: {
                     input: "$products",
                     cond: { $eq: ["$$this._id", "$$product"] }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   {
      $set: {
         products: {
            $map: {
               input: "$products",
               in: {
                  _id: { $first: "$$this._id" },
                  quantity: { $sum: "$$this.quantity" }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   {
      $set: {
         products: {
            $firstN: {
               input: {
                  $sortArray: {
                     input: "$products",
                     sortBy: { quantity: -1 }
                  }
               },
               n: 3
            }
         }
      }
   },
   { $unwind: '$products' },
   {
      $group: {
         _id: '$products._id',
         unitsSold: { $sum: '$products.quantity' }
      }
   }
])
```

However, above query will fail if you have products which are sold by many restaurants but with low quantity each.

Comment: Do you think what It can somehow be done easier with code? I'm using Node.js

Comment: And by the way, the aggeragrtions you provided take about 2 times longer then my original one

Comment: Then it will be difficult. Reading one million documents and unwind it to 10 million documents just takes time.